# Z value is lost when converting QgsGeometry to PointZ with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, geometry, convert, z-value

I want to create a `PointZ` with a Z value, then construct a geometry, and then go back to a `PointZ` but the Z value is lost because `.asPoint()` is returning a `PointXY`.

```py
p = QgsPoint(1,2,3)
print(p)
#<QgsPoint: PointZ (1 2 3)>

g = QgsGeometry(p)
print(g)
#<QgsGeometry: PointZ (1 2 3)>

p2 = g.asPoint()
print(p2)
#<QgsPointXY: POINT(1 2)> #The Z is lost
```

How can I create a `PointZ` from the geometry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is:

```py
p = QgsPoint(1,2,3)
print(p)
#<QgsPoint: PointZ (1 2 3)>

g = QgsGeometry(p)
print(g)
#<QgsGeometry: PointZ (1 2 3)>

p2 = g.constGet()
print(p2)
#<QgsPoint: PointZ (1 2 3)>
```

`QgsPoint` is the underlying geometry contained inside the `QgsGeometry` it does not need to be recreated from WKT or anything else, just accessed.

***NB:*** [`.constGet()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.constGet) gets a non-modifiable point if you want to change the point, you need to use [`.get()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.get).

Comment: I didn't know this solution, +1 and I think it's the best answer.